# AHK Script doesn't open terminal in C:\ Directory, but does in others

Tags: autohotkey

First of all my code:

```
#t::
IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass ; If explorer is active
{
    path := GetActiveExplorerPath()
    Run wt.exe -d "%path%"
}
else 
{
    Run wt.exe
}
Return

; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253268/autohotkey-and-windows-10-how-to-get-current-explorer-path 
GetActiveExplorerPath() {
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    if (explorerHwnd)
    {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            if (window.hwnd==explorerHwnd)
                return window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
        }
    } 
}
```

Now if I press `[Superkey] + [t]` then the terminal opens as intended. However, a bug occurs if there is a space in the path variable, i.e. `C:\Users\user\AHK Macros`.

Fixing this should be easy (wrapping it in double quotes) and it works. The problem now is that opening the terminal at the `C:\` directory results in an error. I think it has something to do with `C:\` ending in a "\", thus escaping the quotation mark. Not sure though. I have tried wrapping it in 3/4 quotes. Printing it with `MsgBox` does give the desired `"C:/"` result and I am able to open `C:/` if I leave out the quotation marks. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Is your default in wt powershell, or something else?

Comment: @0x464e Yes my default is Windows Terminal (Preview), but it opens PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would indeed need to escape the last backslash.
For example
`Run, % "wt.exe -d ""C:\"""` <sub><sup>(in legacy syntax `Run, wt.exe -d "C:\"`)</sup></sub> is not fine
but
`Run, % "wt.exe -d ""C:\\"""` <sub><sup>(in legacy syntax `Run, wt.exe -d "C:\\"`)</sup></sub> is fine.

You can for example check if the path ends in `\` <sub><sup>(should only happen in drive roots, I think)</sup></sub> and then add an extra backslash:

```
#t::
    if (WinActive("ahk_exe Explorer.EXE ahk_class CabinetWClass"))
    {
        path := GetActiveExplorerPath()
        if (SubStr(path, 0) == "\") ;get last character
            path .= "\"
        path := StrReplace(path, ";", "\;") ;semicolon needs to be escaped
        Run, % "wt.exe -d """ path """"
    }
    else 
    {
        Run, % "wt.exe"
    }
return
```

And you'll notice that I also escaped `;`, that needs to be done as well because it separates commands in wt launch parameters.

`SubStr()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SubStr.htm)</sup>

`StrReplace()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrReplace.htm)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! Answer choses as accepted. Thank you for the help :)!