# (Windows › Cygwin › grep › Notepad++) Open grep-found files with spaces

Tags: grep, cygwin

I added *Notepad++* to *Cygwin*. I'd like to be able to find files and open them with one single command, I think about something like this:

```
npp $(grep -l -r 'phrase')
```

The problem is that it seems not to be able to open files which have spaces within names... :( Could this command may be modified to do the job?

Comment: Quoting might help, `npp "$(grep -l -r 'phrase')"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank You, unfortunately it didn't:

`cygpath: can't convert empty path`

I'm sorry to delete Your comment by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -l` separates filenames with a newline. You need to see newline as an argument splitter,
and not to split on ordinary space.

Also, when generating a list of files you want to operate on, *xargs* is in order.

```
$ grep -l -R 'regex' | xargs -d '\n' npp
```

If your filenames may have a newline in them (yeah, unlikely on windows), use null as the separator:

```
$ grep -l -R -Z 'regex' | xargs -0 npp
```

Less typing, and more general to boot.

Comment: Thank You. My test files have "ico" text inside. If I use:

`$ grep -l -R 'ico' | xargs -d '\n' npp`

I get:

`xargs: npp: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just what the error says: _xargs_ cannot see a command call _npp_. Is _npp_ on your `$PATH`? Is it an alias? What does `$ type npp` say?

Comment: > "Is npp on your $PATH? Is it an alias?"  



To * .baschrc* file (home directory) I added:  



`npp () {
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin $(cygpath -w -- "$@")
}`



> "What does $ type npp say?"   



`npp is a function   
npp ()   
{   
    /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin $(cygpath -w -- "$@")   
}`

Comment: Aliases and shell functions only work inside _bash_. _Xargs_ requires an actual command. So make your _npp_ a shell script, and put it in a folder on your `$PATH`. There exist other options too, but they don't fit in a comment!

Comment: > "make your npp a shell scripts and put it on your $PATH"   

Would You be willing to point out how to do this? I'm a beginner in this field, I can do the research on how to make "shell scripts", but I don't know what I should put on My "$PATH".

Comment: That's a different question! Just put the commands into a file `npp`. Put `npp` into a folder where you might put other commands (`~/bin/` say (i.e., the `bin/` folder in your `$HOME` directory)). Ensure that folder is on your `$PATH` — put `PATH=~/bin:$PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile` maybe.

Comment: I put npp code snippet into "npp" file (~/bin). Within .bash_profile file I found this:

`# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
 # if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
   # PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
 # fi`
 
 and removed three last "#". I also removed npp code snippet from .baschrc. Cygwin relaunched and npp gives 
 
 `bash: npp: command not found`

Comment: Interestingly, when I do the same command inside the main Cygwin window, I get:

`$ npp
/home/Thomas/bin/npp: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'home/Thomas/bin/npp: line 1: `npp () {
`

I changed the "npp" file content into

`/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin $(cygpath -w -- "$@")`

and now it opens Notepad on "npp" - but only within the main Cygwin window. If I switch to another directory within Cygwin window, "npp" gives: "npp: command not found
".

Comment: _Cygwin relaunched and npp gives bash: npp: command not found_: `$ type npp` will tell you what _bash_ makes of the command (obviously not found). `$ tr : \\n <<<$PATH` will print out your `$PATH` nicely. Is your ~/bin/ folder on the list? Add it manually `$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH` and ensure `$ type npp` says `npp is /home/blah/bin/npp` (or somesuch)

Comment: _line 1: syntax error near unexpected token $'{\r'' '_ This may be due to the file having dos line endings. Run `dos2unix` or similar to ensure it has unix line endings.

Comment: > "ensure $ type npp says npp is /home/blah/bin/npp"  

Yes, it gives this message - but if I run _Cygwin_ from other directory, it gives that:  

`Thomas@Evelyn /cygdrive/d/x  
$ type npp  
bash: type: npp: not found`

Comment: What on Earth does _but if I run Cygwin from other directory_ mean?

Comment: I have a directory on disk f. If I run _Cygwin_ by default (a _Cygwin_ desktop icon) and navigate to this directory (by "cd"), it works fine - I can initiate "npp" from this directory.

But I use this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140240/autohotkey-script-to-open-command-prompt/55735367#55735367 ) to open _Cygwin_ automatically within a directory from Windows Explorer window. And if I launch _Cygwin_ this way - in the exact same directory as the one mentioned above - the "npp" command does not work.

Comment: In each of those shells look at `$PATH`. `.bash_profile` is only sourced in _login_ shells. Likely those started with a `-l` parameter.

Comment: Main window:    
`Thomas@Evelyn ~
$ $PATH.
-bash: /home/Kić: No such file or directory`


The other window with custom directory:   
`Thomas@Evelyn /cygdrive/d/x
$ $PATH.
bash: /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory`

Seems like there is problem with folders with spaces within their names (like "Program Files").

Comment: Here you asked _bash_ to expand `$PATH` and to try to execute the result as a command(!). Don't do that. Just print out the value of `$PATH`: `$ echo "$PATH"`. Or if you want it a bit neater: `$ tr : \\n <<<"$PATH"`. (Don't type in the `$` prefix — I just use it to indicate it's a command-line.)

Answer (score 0):

It's worth writing up another way around this problem.
Command substitution (that's the `$(`…`)` construct) splits the output of the command into separate arguments.
It splits on the characters in the `$IFS` variable.
By default, these are the three white-space characters *space*, *tab* and *newline*.

Since you are unlikely to encounter newlines or tabs in your filenames,
one option is to tinker with `$IFS`, removing the space character.

```
$ IFS=$'\t\n'
$ npp $(grep -l -r 'regex')
```

I don't recommend you change your `$IFS` globally.

Comment: > "I don't recommend you change your $IFS globally."

Why? (what place better than within this thread should I ask this question?)

Comment: Other scripts are likely to rely on its default value, and it's extremely rare that scripts set `$IFS`. The idiom is that if you change it, you should change it back afterwards.

Comment: The _IFS_ command works until I close _Cygwin_ (even if I run _Cygwin_ as an admin). I've searched for _IFS_ file within _Cygwin_ folder, to no avail.

But it's great it works at least temporarily :) .

Comment: In this context, IFS is not a command, it's a shell variable. When you set it, it exists only in that _bash_ process. If it has the _export_ attribute it will be put in the environment of any new processes that that _bash_ starts. IFS is not usually exported. _bash_ responds to many variables. If you want IFS always to have a non-default value, then you will need to set it in the appropriate one of _bash_'s many start-up files.

Comment: Thank You for clarifying this. I need to _Google_ where the _IFS_ value is stored then :) .

Comment: Normally scripts are happy with the default value of `$IFS` and never set or fiddle with it. Just occasionally a script will modify its local copy for its own internal reasons.